# C# Adding items to MainForm ListBox from a different class

Tags: c#

I'm still fairly new to programming, and have started a project where I'm trying to seperate functionality of the program into classes, where each class handles most everything related to that specific part of the program.

I have one class, called DirectoryMonitors, that creates an object that monitors a directory with FileSystemWatcher.  I'm trying to add items to a ListBox on the MainForm from an instance of this DirectoryMonitors class.  However, it seems I'm unable to call the method in MainForm unless it's static - but if it's static, I can't access my ListBox.

Relevant part of my DirectoryMonitor class:

```
public class DirectoryMonitorData
{
    public bool WatcherActive { get; set; } = true;
    public string EQVersion { get; set; }
    public string FolderLocation { get; set; }
}

public class DirectoryMonitor : DirectoryMonitorData
{

    private void FolderWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        if (!IsFileLocked(fi))
        {
            int startPos = e.FullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
            int endPos = e.FullPath.IndexOf("-Inventory") - startPos;
            string character = e.FullPath.Substring(startPos, endPos);
            MessageBox.Show(character);

            string[] delimiters = { ControlChars.Tab.ToString() };
            using (TextFieldParser parser = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser(e.FullPath, delimiters))
            {
                // Process the file's lines.
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                        MainForm.addLogToListBox(fields[0]);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Relevant part of my MainForm class:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
{


    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void addLogToListBox(string logMessage)
    {
        logsListBox.Items.Insert(0, logMessage);
    }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
    public FileSystemWatcher FolderWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        public DirectoryMonitor()
        {
            FolderWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            FolderWatcher.Filter = "*-Inventory.txt";
            FolderWatcher.Changed += FolderWatcher_Changed;
        }

public void setupDirectoryMonitorList()
        {
            foreach (DirectoryMonitorData dmd in MainForm.directoryMonitorList)
            {
                DirectoryMonitor dm = new DirectoryMonitor()
                {
                    WatcherActive = dmd.WatcherActive,
                    FolderLocation = dmd.FolderLocation,
                    EQVersion = dmd.EQVersion
                };

                if (dm.WatcherActive)
                {
                    dm.FolderWatcher.Path = dm.FolderLocation;
                    dm.FolderWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    dm.FolderWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                    dm.FolderWatcher.Filter = "*-Inventory.txt";
                    dm.FolderWatcher.Changed += FolderWatcher_Changed;
                }
                MainForm.directoryMonitorObjects.Add(dm);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I normally do that is to add a `constructor` to the class, that takes a `'MainForm'` parameter, then save the `'MainForm'` parameter in a field.

```
public class DirectoryMonitor : DirectoryMonitorData
{

    public DirectoryMonitor(MainForm form)
    {
        this.mainForm = form;
    }

    private MainForm mainForm;

}
```

Now you can access all `public` methods an properties of `MainForm` by using the field `mainForm`.

**Alternative**:

Create an `eventhandler` in your class (with a custom `EventArgs`). Then from your 'MainForm', subscribe to that event. Now the class does not have to know anything about the form. You just need to `Invoke` the eventhandler in your class.

Comment: I updated the post to show more code.  Your solution I think would require the objects to be created in the MainForm class?  Which is not what I'm trying to do.  I did try to move the creation to the MainForm class, and that opened up a slew of new issues, and still didn't work (I got an error about threading as well).

Comment: Well, no matter what, you must tell your class, what 'MainForm' is, passing a reference to it.

Comment: VS doesn't throw any errors now when I try to access it using your method, but when I run it, and it makes the attempt to access the ListBox, I get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'logsListBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: You're calling from a background thread, you need to use 'Invoke' to get back on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks so much, looking up what Invoke was/how to use it got me to a working solution!  This is why I'm doing these projects, to learn new things!

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to your `DirectoryMonitorData` class and pass list box to it:

```
public class DirectoryMonitorData
{
    public bool WatcherActive { get; set; } = true;
    public string EQVersion { get; set; }
    public string FolderLocation { get; set; }
    public ListBox Logs {get; set;}
}
```

and then:

```
DirectoryMonitor monitor = new DirectoryMonitor  { Logs = logsListBox };
```

now in your class you can simply add anything to that listbox:

```
Logs.Items.Add(Something);
```